# Tomcat : using double-quote character in a context parameter name

Tags: jsp, tomcat, deployment-descriptor

I don't find the correct syntax for using the double-quote character in a context parameter name that I want do declare in the deployment descriptor file.

Here's the parameter definition in web.xml :

```
<context-param>
<param-name>Catalina:type=GlobalRequestProcessor,name=\"http-nio-8080\"</param-name>
<param-value>requestCount</param-value>
</context-param>
```

the following JSP code :

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*,javax.management.*"%>
JMX testing
<%
  Enumeration ipn = application.getInitParameterNames();

  String ipnName = "";
  while(ipn.hasMoreElements()) {
    ipnName = (String)ipn.nextElement();

    ObjectName on = new ObjectName( ipnName );
  }
%>
```

triggers this Exception:

> HTTP Status 500 – Internal
>   Server Errorh1
>   {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;}
>   h2
>   {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;}
>   h3
>   {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;}
>   body
>   {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;}
>   b
>   {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} p
>   {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}
>   a {color:black;} a.name {color:black;} .line
>   {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}
>
> ## HTTP
>   Status 500 – Internal Server Error
>
> **Type** Exception Report
>
> **Message**
>   javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException: Invalid character
>   '"' in value part of property
>
> **Description**
>   The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from
>   fulfilling the
>   request.
>
> **Exception**
>
> ```
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException:
> javax.servlet.ServletException:
> javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException: Invalid character
> '"' in value part of property
>         org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:598)
>         org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:499)
>         org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
>         org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
>         javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>         org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
> ```
>
> **Root Cause**
>
> ```
> javax.servlet.ServletException:
> javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException: Invalid character
> '"' in value part of property
>         org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:909)
>         org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:838)
>         org.apache.jsp.ko_jsp._jspService(ko_jsp.java:138)
>         org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>         javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>         org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
>         org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
>         org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
>         javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>         org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
> ```
>
> **Root
>   Cause**
>
> ```
> javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException:
>   Invalid character '"' in value part of property
>           java.management/javax.management.ObjectName.construct(ObjectName.java:621)
>           java.management/javax.management.ObjectName.<init>(ObjectName.java:1406)
>           org.apache.jsp.ko_jsp._jspService(ko_jsp.java:122)
>           org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>           javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>           org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
>           org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
>           org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
>           javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>           org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
> ```

I have tried changing [JASPER strictQuoteEscaping](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jasper-howto.html) value and different syntaxes without effect. I am running Tomcat 8.5.40 with Java 9 u181

By the way calling this JMX directly is working well :

`<%@ page import="java.util.*,javax.management.*"%>
JMX testing
<%
  ObjectName on = new ObjectName("Catalina:type=GlobalRequestProcessor,name=\"http-nio-8080\"");
%>`

Am I missing anything obvious ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to escape the `"` characters if it's between tags. Basically the string between the `<param-name>` tags:

```
<param-name>Catalina:type=GlobalRequestProcessor,name=\"http-nio-8080\"</param-name>
```

is equal to the string (note the three back-slashes):

```
Catalina:type=GlobalRequestProcessor,name=\\\"http-nio-8080\\\"
```

So when specifying the object name in the web.xml, just do it as you would write it on paper (i.e. without the backslashes):

```
<param-name>Catalina:type=GlobalRequestProcessor,name="http-nio-8080"</param-name>
```

### UPDATE (about the second issue from the comments)

> This doesn't work, this time the exception is
>   org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException: Key properties cannot
>   be empty Did you try your suggestion on a Tomcat with JMX correctly
>   configured and enabled ?

The `key properties` are the key-value pairs after the colon. In your example you have two keys:

- type=GlobalRequestProcessor
- name="http-nio-8080"

So the only explanation is that this exception is caused either because:

- using another constructor (unlikely, your code in the question uses the correct one)
- You have more context parameters than shown, and some of them do not have anything after the `:`. Note that you are iterating over all context params and some of them might not be object names: `while(ipn.hasMoreElements())`

You can find the context param that causes the issue simply by printing its name:

```
<%
    Enumeration ipn = application.getInitParameterNames();

    String ipnName;
    while (ipn.hasMoreElements()) {
        ipnName = (String) ipn.nextElement();
        try {
            ObjectName on = new ObjectName(ipnName);
            out.println("<br>Good param: " + ipnName);
        }catch (Exception e){
            out.println("<br>Bad param: " + ipnName);
        }
    }
%>
```

Comment: This doesn't work, this time the exception is `org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException: Key properties cannot be empty
` Did you try your suggestion on a Tomcat with JMX correctly configured and enabled ?

Comment: The Exception above probably means we're calling this wrong constructor [ObjectName(String domain, String key, String value)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/management/ObjectName.html#ObjectName(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) instead of [ObjectName(String name)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/management/ObjectName.html#ObjectName(java.lang.String)). Not that obvious to solve I think.

Comment: The 'key' properties are the 'type' and 'name' attributes. I'd suggest that you log/print the string you are using to create the 'ObjectName'.

Comment: As you suggested, using `out.println(ipnName)` gives this output :  `JMX testing  
Catalina:type=GlobalRequestProcessor,name="http-nio-8080"`

Comment: bounty is opened if interested.

Comment: My guess is that you have additional `<context-param>` entries and some of them are invalid. The one as logged is correct (in terms of ObjectName's contract) and should work (if you remove the "jmx testing" part from it). Also your code does not match what's shown in the question. For instance the `JMX testing ` substring is not present in the `println` and the `context-param`, yet it was logged.

Comment: I don't have additional entries, I wrote a minimal config and tested different syntax before opening a question here which I think is an mcve. In my question you can see where `JMX testing` is coming from. Take 5 minutes and run my code, myself I did not find what is wrong.

Comment: Ok, so here is a minimal app, using olnly your code and it works as expected on my tomcat8: https://github.com/SvetlinZarev/org.example.mcve.web/commit/f400962ab301010ec4c9ba7ac9dd1747a522b5b1

Comment: This is working without being different from what I had. Maybe my files were corrupted (non printable char in `vi`) or the compiled JSP was not refreshed correctly. I don't find any other serious reason. The bounty cannot be given for now, just wait. And thanks.